# What's the point of the tag "laws-of-physics"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As mentioned previously, whenever I have time, I am trying to add descriptions to tags which are yet undefined. I came across the [`laws-of-physics`](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-physics) tag which is refering to only 37 questions (as of February 12, 2021), and is missing a definition. My favorite definition would be that it refers to [first principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_principle) but that's not quite how the tag is currently used. In my mind, there are some alternatives:

1. Define it as synonym to [`modeling`](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling) which is also only is used sparsely (28 times as of February 12, 2021).
2. Introduce a tag `first-principles`, delete the tag `laws-of-physics` and retag questions appropriately.
3. Just retag questions, and delete `laws-of-physics`.

I have a tendency for the last option, but what do you think?

Comment: All right, it looks like all of the questions are gone from this tag. Now we just have to make sure no one recreates this tag. If you see it pop up on a question, just retag it for them with a more specific tag and leave a comment for them explaining why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this seems like a junk tag. My inclination would be to retag the questions with more specific tags. When there are no [laws-of-physics](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws-of-physics) questions left, the tag will be automatically deleted.